# Model values not carrying into partial view from main view- C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, html.renderpartial

I've been stumped for days.

I have an index page that contains a renderpartial view. A viewmodel is passed to the index page from its controller, then passed from inside the index.cshtml to the renderpartial view as an extension.  The renderpartial view is automatically updated every 10 seconds (via jquery function to the controller from the index page) to update its content, which works fine.  The index page contains several checkboxfor's that filter out the contents of the renderpartial view.  The problem arises when the initial renderpartial view is called when the time period has elapsed, the controller for the renderpartial view does not have the correct model data the controller for the index had prior. Boolean values in the model which were set to true while in the index controller now are false when we get to the renderpartial view.  Lets begin...

My Index View:

```
@model SelfServe_Test2.Models.NGTransCertViewModel

...        

    <div class="Services_StatusTable" id="refreshme">        
    @{            
        Html.RenderPartial("_Data", Model);
    }            
    </div>

...

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.NGTransServicesModel.filter_NJDVSVR24, new { onclick = "test(id)" }) @Html.Label("NJDVSVR24", new { })

...

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(function () { $('#refreshme').load('/NGTransCertServices/Data'); }, 10000); // every 10 seconds

    function test(filter) {
        alert(filter);
        var serviceChecked = document.getElementById(filter).checked;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/NGTransCertServices/ToggleVisibleService",
            data: { 'filterOnService': filter, 'serviceChecked': serviceChecked, 'model': @Model },
            //success: function (result) {
            //    if (result === "True")
            //        alert("yup");
            //    else
            //        alert("nope");
            //}
        });
    }

</script>
```

The PartialView _Data.cshtml:

```
@model SelfServe_Test2.Models.NGTransCertViewModel

...

<table>
foreach (var item in Model.NGTransServicesList)
{

    if (Model.NGTransServicesModel.filter_EBT == true)
    {
        if (item.Description.Contains("EBT"))
        {

        }
    }
}
</table>
```

My ViewModel:

```
namespace SelfServe_Test2.Models
{
public class NGTransCertViewModel
{
    public NGTransCertViewModel()
    {
        NGTransServicesModel = new NGTransCertServicesModel();
        NGTransServicesList = new List<NGTransCertServicesList>();
        NGTransServices = new NGTransCertServices();
    }
    public NGTransCertServicesModel NGTransServicesModel { get; set; }
    public List<NGTransCertServicesList> NGTransServicesList { get; set; }
    public NGTransCertServices NGTransServices { get; set; }
}
}
```

The Controller:

```
 public class NGTransCertServicesController : Controller
{
    NGTransCertViewModel NGT_VM = new NGTransCertViewModel();
    NGTransCertServicesModel certServicesModel = new NGTransCertServicesModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        NGTransCertServices certServices = new NGTransCertServices();                        
        NGT_VM.NGTransServicesModel = certServices.InitServiceTypeCheckBoxes(certServicesModel);   // sets all checkboxes to true initially.
        return View(NGT_VM);
    }


    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 10)]    // in seconds
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        NGTransCertDBHandle certDBHandle = new NGTransCertDBHandle();
        List<NGTransCertServicesList> List_certServices = certDBHandle.GetService();
        return PartialView("_Data", NGT_VM);
    }
}
```

Finally, the model where the values are lost:

```
 public class NGTransCertServicesModel
{
    ...
    public bool filter_NJDVSVR24 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now then, when the Index.cshtml page is called, i run the InitServiceTypeCheckBoxes method that sets the checkbox values to true, pass the viewmodel to the index page and pass that same model to the renderpartial. All is happy until the 10s timeout is reached and _Data.cshtml is rendered.  The checkbox values are now all false.

Let me add a visual element. Below is the model when returning from the controller to the index view with the Boolean set to true as desired. (stepping through)
[image]

Below is the model when the index view
[image]

Again, in the _Data.cshtml partial view
[image]

Now with a breakpoint in the Data action in the controller, that same bool value is now false
[image]

The bool does not have the true value even before the first line of code in the Data action.

```
NGTransCertDBHandle certDBHandle = new NGTransCertDBHandle();
```

Comment: In the `Data` action you're passing `List<NGTransCertServicesList>` but the partial view expect `SelfServe_Test2.Models.NGTransCertViewModel`. It should lead to an exception.

Comment: Unrelated, but unless you have to support IE 6-8 you should really try and use a more modern version of JQuery than 1.12.

Comment: Thanks, i do need to use a more recent JQuery version.  I added some visuals to help flesh out my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're not populating your view model correctly in the `Data` method of your controller.

In both methods you're sending the `NGT_VM` property to the view, but you only populate some of the data in the `Index` method - this data will not be persisted or created by default when you call the `Data` method.

Each time a request hits a controller method, that controller is created afresh, and only the constructor and requested method are called. In the case of a request to `Data` the controller is created, the `NGT_VM` property is set back to the default `NGTransCertViewModel` object, with a default `NGTransCertServicesModel` object (the boolean property `filter_NJDVSVR24` will default to `false`). You then create and ignore a variable `List_certServices`, but at no point have you updated the `NGTransServicesModel` property on the view model to match the values you had from the `Index` method.

You should probably assign the `NGTransServicesList` variable to the `NGT_VM.NGTransServicesList` after you populate it:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, 
             Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client,
             Duration = 10)]
public ActionResult Data()
{
    NGTransCertDBHandle certDBHandle = new NGTransCertDBHandle();
    List<NGTransCertServicesList> List_certServices = certDBHandle.GetService();
    NGT_VM.NGTransServicesList = List_certServices;
    return PartialView("_Data", NGT_VM);
}
```

You could either call same methods to update the `NGTransServicesModel` as required in the `Data` method, but I'm not sure that's really the behaviour you're after?

Comment: i added some visual support of the issue. the value is lost before the first line of code in the Data action is executed.

Comment: @JasonBeck If that final picture is taken while you're in the `Data` method, that is expected - you only populate the `NGTransServicesModel` in the `Index` method. The properties in your controller will not persist between requests meaning you will need to recreate your model in each method (or recreate it in a constructor that is called before either method).

Comment: thanks for the input.  for some reason i though it would persist since 'certServicesModel ' is outside the methods, but it clearly doesn't work that way.  For the way the site currently works, i think a recreation is a constructor is the best option, thanks for you insight!

Comment: No probs, glad to have helped :)